# vba return first row number in column that has todays date or nearest date after today

Tags: excel, vba, date, find, cell

VBA Code solution required. I have a column of dates in Column D of my excel spreadsheet. These dates are not continuous and so may not contain todays date and may be missing todays date.  I wish to return the first row number of cell in that column that either matches todays date or if todays date doesnt exist, then select the next nearest future date after today.  I wish the code to return a variable, todaydate = first row number of cell that is today or next nearest today afterwards.  In the example below, if todays date was 28th February 2023, todayrow = 5 , ie the first nearest future date is 3/3/23.   If today 27/3/23 then today = 2, ie first row with todays date.  I am not interedted in returning a row number for nearest past dates

```
Row Number       Date

 1               26-Feb-23
 2               27-Feb-23
 3               27-Feb-23
 4               27-Feb-23
 5               03-Mar-23
 6               03-Mar-23
 7               03-Mar-23
 8               04-Mar-23
 9               05-Mar-23
10               05-Mar-23
11               08-Mar-23
12               07-Mar-23
```

Read various threads but none do exacty what I describe above in vba

Comment: *if todays date was 28th February 2023, todayrow = 5 , ie the first nearest date is 3/3/23* The nearest date to 28th Feburary 2023 in your data is 27th February, not 3/3/23. Please, clarify exactly why is 3/3/23 and not 27th February. Sounds like a row combined with sumproduct functions may be helpful here.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns thanks for your reply,  I perhaps should have said "nearest date in the Future".  Not interested in the past date.  Hence I would like Row 5 returned if today is 28/3/23.  I will see if I can edit my question

Comment: *VBA Code solution required* You could design and UDF to get this. Please, post the code you've deployed and what errors are you getting

Comment: k1drock code answered my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub FindDate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim searchDate As Date
    
    'set worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'set search date, change accordingly
    searchDate = CDate("04-Feb-23")
    
    'search for first match date in column D
    Set foundCell = ws.Columns("D").Find(What:=searchDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    
    'if not found, search for first instance of a date greater than today
    Do While foundCell Is Nothing
        searchDate = searchDate + 1
        Set foundCell = ws.Columns("D").Find(What:=searchDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    Loop
    
    'if a match is found, select the cell and display a message
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        foundCell.Select
        MsgBox "Found date  in row " & foundCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "No matching date or greater than the date found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks k1dr0ck.  Just what I needed!!